# How do I fix this error: "Error: Cannot find module './commands/info/status.js'" discordJS

Tags: discord.js

hander "command.js"

```js
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');
const ascii = require('ascii-table');

const client = require('..');
const { dir } = require('console');
const { config } = require('process');
let table = new ascii("Commands");
table.setHeading('Commands', 'Load');

module.exports = (client) => {

    readdirSync('./commands/').forEach(dir => {
        const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
        for(const file of commands) {
            const pull = require(`./commands/${dir}/${file}`);
            if (pull.name) {
                client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
                slash.push(pull);
                table.addRow(file, "OK");
            }else {
                table.addRow(file, 'Error - Missing a help.name or it is not a string...');
                continue;
            }if(pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name))
        }
    });
    console.log(table.toString());


    readdirSync('./events/').forEach((file) => {                
        const events = readdirSync('./events').filter((file) => 
        file.endsWith('.js')
        );
        for (let file of events) {
            let pull = require(`../events/${file}`);
            if(pull.name) {
                client.events.set(pull.name, pull)
            }
        }
        console.log(`${file} Events load`);
    })
}
```

event "messageCreate.js"

```js
const { Embed, Collection } = require('discord.js')
const client = require('..');
const config = require('../setting/config.json');
const prefix_bot = config.prefix_bot;

client.on("messageCreste", async (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix_bot)) return;
    if(!message.guild) return;
    if(!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix_bot.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

    const cmd =  args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(cmd.length == 0) return;
    let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    if(!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));
    if(command) command.run(client, message,  args)
});
```

commands "status.js"

```js
const { Embed, Collection } = require('discord.js')
const client = require('..');
const config = require('../setting/config.json');
const prefix_bot = config.prefix_bot;

client.on("messageCreste", async (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix_bot)) return;
    if(!message.guild) return;
    if(!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix_bot.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

    const cmd =  args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if(cmd.length == 0) return;
    let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    if(!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));
    if(command) command.run(client, message,  args)
});
```

error

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './commands/info/status.js'
> Require stack:
> C:\Users\satang\Desktop\bot_node_satang\dis3\handler\command.js
> C:\Users\satang\Desktop\bot_node_satang\dis3\index.js
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
> at C:\Users\satang\Desktop\bot_node_satang\dis3\handler\command.js:15:26
> at Array.forEach ()
> at module.exports (C:\Users\satang\Desktop\bot_node_satang\dis3\handler\command.js:12:32)
> at C:\Users\satang\Desktop\bot_node_satang\dis3\index.js:68:34
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Object. (C:\Users\satang\Desktop\bot_node_satang\dis3\index.js:67:13) {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: [
> 'C:\Users\satang\Desktop\bot_node_satang\dis3\handler\command.js',
> 'C:\Users\satang\Desktop\bot_node_satang\dis3\index.js'
> ]
> }

Can anyone find the error?
HELP ME PLESSS

Comment: To require that file you need to export something from it, like a function, an object or something, put that client.on() in a function and export that function using `module.exports = `, also `pull.name` will be undefined as you don't export the value `name`, the same with the event `messageCreate.js`

Comment: And there is no `messageCreste` event.